# How to generate a google signed JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, jwt

How do I get a sign JWT token using the google-auth-library and node js?

my code:

```
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library'
import keys from './jwt.keys.json';
class SecurityServices {
    async getGoogleWebToken() {
        const client = new JWT({
            email: keys.client_email,
            key: keys.private_key,
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
        });
        const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
        const res = await client.request({ url });
       
        console.log(client.credentials.access_token);
        console.log(client.credentials.token_type);
        console.log(client.credentials.id_token);

    }
}
```

**Result**

access token = ya29.otherchar......................................

token_type  = bearer

id_token =undefined

As you can access token has a series of "." and id_token is undefined

Basically,  I  have a google service account and I want to make a sign JWT with RSA-256 using the private key found in my service account JSON file.

This is an example in java
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

Thanks

Comment: Using the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) node module with a service account maybe the easiest way to use any Google API. Are you trying to retrieve DNS information of a particular project?

Comment: we have some backend restful API that was using GCP API keys and now we switching to JWT.. So, I need the GCP JWT token to communicate with API'a

Comment: The code to generate an Access Token and an Identity Token are different. The first requires scopes, the second requires an audience. Signed JWTs are not supported by most Google Cloud APIs. What are you trying to accomplish? Note: Your code is creating an OAuth 2.0 Access Token which is used to call Google Cloud APIs. Internally the code created a Signed JWT and then exchanged it for an Access Token.

Comment: Where are you running your code? On your workstation?

Comment: I am running the code on my Mac.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the response .. I  have a google service account and I want to make a sign JWT with RSA-256 using the private key found in my service account JSON file.

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question. There are different types of JWT. What are you using the JWT for?

Comment: my api's are in k8s cluster  that I access via a API keys.. I now need to access it via JWT using the service account.

Comment: That still does not answer my question. I recommend reading about authorization in Google Cloud so that you understand how authorization is performed, the types of tokens, and how they are formed.

Comment: Thank, I will do that.. but this what I am trying to accomplish in nodejs ... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```js
/**
 * Generates signed JWT for GCP vault auth
 * @param {string} serviceAccountEmail
 * @param {string} projectId
 * @param {Object} claims
 */
const getSignedJwt = async (serviceAccountEmail, projectId, claims) => {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    name: `projects/${projectId}/serviceAccounts/${serviceAccountEmail}`,
    resource: {
      payload: JSON.stringify(claims),
    },
    auth: authClient,
  };
  try {
    const response = (await iam.projects.serviceAccounts.signJwt(request)).data;
    return response.signedJwt;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const authorize = async () => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
  });
  return await auth.getClient();
};

/**
 * Generates claims object for JWT
 * @param {string} roleName
 * @param {string} serviceAccountEmail
 */

const getJwtClaims = (roleName, serviceAccountEmail) => {
  const timeExp = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 600;
  const claims = {
    aud: `vault/${roleName}`,
    exp: timeExp,
    sub: serviceAccountEmail,
  };
  return claims;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.